# How to get value from Azure App Service from Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cicd

I have a configuration in App Service like this
[image]
I want to pass this setting into the argument of a pipeline's task
[image]
How can I do it?

I've tried to create a variable group but I still don't know how to link the app setting into the variable
[image]

Comment: Where is the app service's configuration value coming from? Why do you need an app service's setting to run something in your pipeline?

Comment: it's coming from the Azure app service in Azure portal. I need them as an argument to run a console app before deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provide command line tools to access this information. I don't have a web-app to access to give specific commands but roughly something like this.

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=cli#configure-app-settings

For example using az cli you could do something like:

`az webapp config connection-string list --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> > settings.json`

You can then select the specific item out of that list using `jq`.

`myvalue=$(jq -r .some.path settings.json)`

And you can also set the value in a variable which you can use in another task:

`##vso[task.setvariable variable=appsetting;]value`

So :

1. Download app settings
2. Select item
3. Set variable to pass to next step
4. Use variable in next step.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am able to retrieve the setting using azure cli